# Recursively change owner of a directory by that directory's name

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

In Ubuntu 16.04 I have a few website directories under `/var/www/html/`.

I desire that the owner of each dir will be identical to the dir's name.

How could I recursively change the owner of a dir by that dir's name?

### Notes:

**1)** I've already created a user per each directory as in:

```
useradd ${domain} --gecos --disabled-password --disabled-login
```

**2)** The purpose of this operation is of security reasons - to prevent all dirs to have the same owner.

Comment: Are there user IDs that match all those directories? Or must they be created? I think only current user IDs can be set as owners.

Comment: Yes, there are. I've edited the question.

Comment: As a security professional, I question your assumption in note #2.  To be *most* secure you would only let superuser have write permissions / ownership.  Since that account is very likely to be locked down, adn files aren't executed as root with a webserver, there's really no *true* security benefit to this, unless you want to segregate what users have access to which directory for the purposes of FTP access or such.  HOWEVER, there's no evidence of that here, and all you are doing is increasing the number of users (and superfluous pollution therein) within your user database on the system.

Comment: Interesting Thomas. I am far from being a security professionalist. I just talked with someone who claims to be a programmer and seems to me to provide hosting services and he recommended me that all sites shouldn't run under the same user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Working script

*Assuming that www-data is the correct group for your web server*

Enter the following with your favourite editor in `chown_www.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for directory in `find /var/www/html/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
    
    user=$(basename $directory)
    chown -R $user:www-data $directory
done
```

make it executable

```
chmod +x /path/to/script/chown_www.sh
```

and execute as root or via sudo

```
sudo /path/to/script/chown_www.sh
```

*Disclaimer: This has no error-check to see if the directory names are viable users (and/or clean names).*

---

## Explanation

The `find` with a min/max depth of 1 will only find directories that are directly located under `/var/www/html` - which is what you want.

`-type d` in case there are some files in `/html`.

Then we get the directory's name with `basename` and do the recursive `chown`, like you wanted.

---

*Disclaimer: This is inspired by user muclux, but my edit was rejected*

Comment: I think `for directory in */` is much simpler and does the same thing in a save way – imagine dir names with spaces or newlines.

Comment: `chown` doesn't need the group name, you can just omit it together with the colon.

Comment: @dessert, I'm choosing the safe option with `chown` since maybe the group was incorrect before(root?). What do you mean with `for directory in */` - I don't see the benefit since `find` is much faster and white-spaces or newlines (or anything else) are not escaped either way. Speaking of *funny* directory names, this whole endeavour has no error checking whatsoever - no cross checking if the dir-name matches an existing user and so on....**BUT** we *could* use double quotes on the `chown` which would help with whitespaces, etc - but I doubt that a username with spaces is viable anyway...

Comment: [Actually everything except `/` and NUL is allowed.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148043/is-space-not-allowed-in-a-filename) I seriously doubt that calling an external program like `find` is any faster than [bash pathname expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs). Your `find` command matches `/var/www/html` itself as well – I solved this problem with `-mindepth 1`, see my answer below.

Comment: [Yeah, sure but not exactly best practice in usernames](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/79956). You can test the speed with `time` it is faster. `-mindepth 1` is not the only thing we can add, since this is `find`and not only bash we can use `-type d` in case there are stray files in `/html` ;-)  --- actually I had min/max depth in the original edit of muclux's answer but the edit was rejected

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your plan is a good one, but the following script could do the job (called with sudo). Please note that you can only use existing userIDs as owners.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www

for file in `find html/*`
do
    d=`dirname $file`
    p=`basename $d`
    chown $p:www-data $file
done
```

The script treats files and subdirectories alike, so there is no need for recursion.

basename (dirname (file)) gives you the name of the immediate "parent" directory.

Comment: Sorry, but hat only works if there are no further subdirectories ! If `usera` had a directory called `root` in his directory ( i.e. `/var/www/usera/root/index.html`), all subsequent files and directories would be owned by `root` !

Comment: Sorry, my edit was rejected and I was advised to post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have N directories below `/var/www/html` and want to change the owner of these top-level directories only (recursively), i.e.

```
/var/www/html/domain1   # -> change owner to "domain1" for this dir and below
/var/www/html/domain2   # -> change owner to "domain2" for this dir and below
/var/www/html/domain3   # -> change owner to "domain3" for this dir and below
```

If e.g. `/var/www/html/domain1` has subdirectories (like `public`, `css`, `data`), then they should *not* belong to a user `public` etc., but also to user `domain1`.

Given this precondition the following scriptlet will work (as user `root`):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /var/www/html
GLOBIGNORE=.    # to catch hidden directories
for dir in *; do
    test -d $dir && chown -R $dir $dir;
done
```

Comment: Use `*/` to match only directories, this way you can save the `test`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `find`?

```bsh
find /var/www/html -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'echo chown -R "${0##*/}" "$0"' {} \;
```

This will simply find all `d`irectories under `/var/www/html/` and not further below and `exec`ute `chown -R` on every single one of them. Inside the bash shell `$0` is the currently processed directory's path and `${0##*/}` is the cut out directory name. I added an `echo` above so that it will print every `chown` command it is going to execute first, if you're happy with the results just run it without the `echo`.

If for any reason you want or need a different approach for the task here are some alternatives (all with the `echo` for testing!), the `parallel` one being the most efficient in case of a *huge* number of directories:

```bsh
for i in /var/www/html/*/; do a=${i%/}; echo chown -R "${a##*/}" "$i"; done
for i in /var/www/html/*/; do echo chown -R "$(dirname $i)" "$i"; done
parallel echo chown -R '{=s/\/$//;s/.*\///=}' {} ::: /var/www/html/*/
```